# alpha channel artifacts intersecting another mesh in cycles

Tags: transparency, artifacts

First off, please do not say its "light path bounces". It's not the bounces.

I have eyebrows on a plane, where there isn't eyebrow is alpha channel, and where the transparency intersects the head, are black lines (put a light inside the head, and you can see it...) this's in cycles, eevee seems fine... (and the pic is with the light inside the head). It's like the alpha channel is effecting the other mesh reading through other posts here, someone else asked this same question but didn't get an answer

[image: alpha intersection]

Comment: Please don't use code for the question, makes it very hard to read. 
If you hide the eyebrows it goes away?

Comment: First off, thank you... I saw that it put the text in that funky box, but couldn't figure out how to edit it, to fix it (first post here), second, yes hide it, and the the artifacts go away, but so do the hair/eyebrows...

Comment: Are the eyebrows actual hair, or a texture and can you show the material setup?

Comment: modified plane with an alpha channel (ironically, since I kinda suck at particle hair, this should'a been faster) seems the artifacts arise where the plane intersects the head  (how the help is saying to add an image in a reply is not working, will try to put the node layout in an edit... neither setup in the image gets ride of the artifacts)

Comment: This's annoying, seem to have no idea how add an image to a reply...   !https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H93JWSOBspJETi4S82gNWg89HjhVd-kh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So, trying to recreate the problem, I put an eyebrow on a sphere, and it didn't have the problem... then I realized the spheres as big as the character, so shrank it... and the artifacts showed up... played with cameras and clipping to no avail...

Comment: you can edit your answer for images. The node setup is correct, are you sure the alpha channel is 100% black where the eyebrows aren't? What happens when you use only a transparent shader?

Comment: inverting the selection in gimp, so pure white, pure black, & totally transparent... nodewise, when just image->transparent->output, when that didn't work, then expanding on that theme.... did mange once to lose the eyebrow, and only have the intersection artifacts....